# Radio button in Label tag in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, radio-button, label, laravel-blade

How to make this code into blade of laravel

```
<label class="radio" for="penyakit-0">
    <input name="penyakit" id="penyakit-0" value="Asma" type="radio">
    Asma
</label>
```

i've tried many ways to the radio button can be clicked from its text by using blade syntax, but still don't get anything right..

This is my blade syntax for that HTML:

```
<label class="radio" for="penyakit-0">
    {{ Form::radio('penyakit', 'Asma', array('id'=>'penyakit-0')) }} 
</label>
```

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? Clicking the `Asma` text doesn't select the radio button?

Comment: I mean. When i change syntax into blade like this:
    {{ Form::radio('penyakit', 'Asma', array('id'=>'penyakit-0')) }}
it won't checked when I click the text 'Asma'

Comment: It's [perfectly fine to wrap the input in a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). So the accepted answer doesn't answer this specific question, unfortunately.

Comment: @phil-gyford Thanks bringing that to our attention! Edit made to the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ Form::label('penyakit-0', 'Asma') }}
{{ Form::radio('penyakit', 'Asma', false, array('id'=>'penyakit-0')) }}
```

## Edit:

As [Phil Gyford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250962/phil-gyford) pointed out above, this Laravel [blade](/questions/tagged/blade) snippet doesn't yield a `label` element with an embedded `input` element.

Unfortunately (or fortunately) by design design Laravel [blade](/questions/tagged/blade) opted for the alternate construction using `for` attribute for some reason.

Comment: You may use **true** instead if you want it checked.